# How to include Welcome msg in header.phtml - Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, template, header

I need to include a welcome message in a custom place of my `header.phtml` file. In Magento 1.9 I could do it with

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?>
```

How to do the same in 2.0?

Comment: You want to change default header.phtml or custom header.phtml ?